How to split a linestring into linestring chunks using sf with R?
The question has been answered, and still I fail at applying it.
I want to split a linestring into a given number of chunks using the sf package.
The road displayed in blue on the map is a linestring named "line", from which I sample 5 points
line <- st_cast(line, "LINESTRING")
line <- st_transform(line, 3857)
pts <- st_line_sample(line,n = 5)

in order to map them I transform them back to lat/lon, and I snap the points to the line as a desperate way to make sure they indeed right on the line:
pts <- st_cast(pts, "POINT")
pts <- st_snap(pts, line, tol=1e-9)
pts <- st_transform(pts,4326)
line <- st_transform(line,4326)

I make sure they look good
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolylines(data=line) %>% addCircleMarkers(data=pts)

and then I split the line
seg <- st_split(x = line, y = pts)
seg2 <- st_collection_extract(seg, "LINESTRING")
print(length(seg))
print(length(seg2))

The lengths remain 1, no matter what I do. The example given on the package webpage works
https://r-spatial.github.io/lwgeom/reference/st_split.html
But in this case it fails.
Here are the coordinates of this line:
> st_coordinates(line)
           X        Y L1
  [1,] -73.47588 45.57844  1
  [2,] -73.47538 45.57834  1
  [3,] -73.47487 45.57824  1
  [4,] -73.47451 45.57817  1
  [5,] -73.47374 45.57799  1
  [6,] -73.47288 45.57779  1
  [7,] -73.47240 45.57767  1
  [8,] -73.47209 45.57760  1
  [9,] -73.47176 45.57752  1
 [10,] -73.47140 45.57744  1
 [11,] -73.47099 45.57734  1
 [12,] -73.47056 45.57725  1
 [13,] -73.47022 45.57716  1
 [14,] -73.46961 45.57703  1
 [15,] -73.46928 45.57696  1
 [16,] -73.46897 45.57689  1
 [17,] -73.46873 45.57684  1
 [18,] -73.46857 45.57681  1
 [19,] -73.46840 45.57678  1
 [20,] -73.46819 45.57674  1
 [21,] -73.46788 45.57668  1
 [22,] -73.46748 45.57660  1
 [23,] -73.46716 45.57654  1
 [24,] -73.46678 45.57647  1
 [25,] -73.46651 45.57642  1
 [26,] -73.46621 45.57636  1
 [27,] -73.46587 45.57630  1
 [28,] -73.46556 45.57623  1
 [29,] -73.46527 45.57617  1
 [30,] -73.46498 45.57611  1
 [31,] -73.46424 45.57598  1
 [32,] -73.46377 45.57588  1
 [33,] -73.46233 45.57557  1
 [34,] -73.46164 45.57541  1
 [35,] -73.46122 45.57531  1
 [36,] -73.45898 45.57478  1
 [37,] -73.45831 45.57463  1
 [38,] -73.45798 45.57456  1
 [39,] -73.45766 45.57449  1
 [40,] -73.45705 45.57436  1
 [41,] -73.45498 45.57391  1
 [42,] -73.45440 45.57379  1
 [43,] -73.45070 45.57300  1
 [44,] -73.44766 45.57235  1
 [45,] -73.44441 45.57166  1
 [46,] -73.44156 45.57105  1
 [47,] -73.43243 45.56910  1
 [48,] -73.43218 45.56905  1
 [49,] -73.43198 45.56901  1
 [50,] -73.43175 45.56896  1
 [51,] -73.43155 45.56892  1
 [52,] -73.43134 45.56889  1
 [53,] -73.43113 45.56885  1
 [54,] -73.43095 45.56882  1
 [55,] -73.43078 45.56880  1
 [56,] -73.43053 45.56877  1
 [57,] -73.43032 45.56874  1
 [58,] -73.43013 45.56871  1
 [59,] -73.42994 45.56869  1
 [60,] -73.42973 45.56867  1
 [61,] -73.42956 45.56866  1
 [62,] -73.42937 45.56864  1
 [63,] -73.42920 45.56863  1
 [64,] -73.42901 45.56862  1
 [65,] -73.42883 45.56861  1
 [66,] -73.42861 45.56860  1
 [67,] -73.42839 45.56859  1
 [68,] -73.42815 45.56858  1
 [69,] -73.42789 45.56858  1
 [70,] -73.42764 45.56858  1
 [71,] -73.42736 45.56858  1
 [72,] -73.42710 45.56859  1
 [73,] -73.42685 45.56860  1
 [74,] -73.42659 45.56861  1
 [75,] -73.42634 45.56862  1
 [76,] -73.42605 45.56864  1
 [77,] -73.42577 45.56865  1
 [78,] -73.42225 45.56885  1
 [79,] -73.42144 45.56890  1
 [80,] -73.41945 45.56900  1
 [81,] -73.41828 45.56907  1
 [82,] -73.41735 45.56912  1
 [83,] -73.41703 45.56914  1
 [84,] -73.41661 45.56916  1
 [85,] -73.41598 45.56920  1
 [86,] -73.41535 45.56923  1
 [87,] -73.41287 45.56937  1
 [88,] -73.41079 45.56948  1
 [89,] -73.41015 45.56952  1
 [90,] -73.40708 45.56969  1
 [91,] -73.40558 45.56977  1
 [92,] -73.40510 45.56980  1
 [93,] -73.40366 45.56988  1
 [94,] -73.40205 45.56996  1
 [95,] -73.40055 45.57005  1
 [96,] -73.39993 45.57008  1
 [97,] -73.39943 45.57011  1
 [98,] -73.39913 45.57013  1
 [99,] -73.39886 45.57015  1
[100,] -73.39862 45.57017  1
[101,] -73.39828 45.57020  1
[102,] -73.39802 45.57022  1
[103,] -73.39779 45.57025  1
[104,] -73.39755 45.57027  1
[105,] -73.39734 45.57030  1
[106,] -73.39711 45.57032  1
[107,] -73.39681 45.57036  1
[108,] -73.39648 45.57040  1
[109,] -73.39609 45.57046  1
[110,] -73.38743 45.57163  1
[111,] -73.38551 45.57189  1
[112,] -73.38328 45.57219  1
[113,] -73.38275 45.57228  1
[114,] -73.38220 45.57236  1
[115,] -73.38090 45.57253  1
[116,] -73.37786 45.57295  1
[117,] -73.37743 45.57301  1
[118,] -73.37270 45.57364  1
[119,] -73.37035 45.57396  1
[120,] -73.36803 45.57428  1
[121,] -73.36627 45.57452  1
[122,] -73.36414 45.57480  1
[123,] -73.36278 45.57499  1
[124,] -73.36221 45.57505  1
[125,] -73.36151 45.57514  1
[126,] -73.36100 45.57521  1
[127,] -73.35975 45.57538  1
[128,] -73.35831 45.57558  1
[129,] -73.35577 45.57592  1
[130,] -73.35447 45.57609  1
[131,] -73.35367 45.57620  1
[132,] -73.35283 45.57632  1
[133,] -73.35195 45.57644  1
[134,] -73.35133 45.57652  1
[135,] -73.35059 45.57662  1
[136,] -73.34979 45.57673  1
[137,] -73.34637 45.57719  1
[138,] -73.34551 45.57730  1
[139,] -73.34409 45.57750  1
[140,] -73.34146 45.57785  1
[141,] -73.33933 45.57814  1
[142,] -73.33868 45.57823  1

[143,] -73.33827 45.57829  1
[144,] -73.33789 45.57834  1
[145,] -73.33755 45.57839  1
[146,] -73.33727 45.57843  1
[147,] -73.33692 45.57848  1
[148,] -73.33661 45.57853  1
[149,] -73.33628 45.57858  1
[150,] -73.33584 45.57865  1
[151,] -73.33530 45.57874  1


Additional comment from the answer: weird enough but points are not enough to split a line, these must be lines, even lines of length null will do it. Following the answer I oriented the code towards this direction:
line <- st_cast(line, "LINESTRING")
line <- st_transform(line, 3857)
pts <- st_line_sample(line,n = 5)
pts <- st_cast(pts, "POINT")
pts <- st_nearest_points(pts,line)
seg <- st_split(line, pts)
seg2 <- st_collection_extract(seg, "LINESTRING")
# Check the number of segments
print(length(seg2))
seg2 <- st_transform(seg2,4326)
pts <- st_transform(pts,4326)
line <- st_transform(line,4326)


I couldn't get st_split to work using points either. However, it works well if you convert the sample points to infinitesimally small line segments:
library(sf)
library(lwgeom)

blades <- line |>
  st_sample(5) |>
  st_cast("POINT") |>
  st_coordinates() |>
  asplit(1) |>
  lapply(function(x) rbind(x + c(0, -1e-6), x + c(0, 1e-6))) |>
  st_multilinestring() |>
  st_sfc(crs = "WGS84")

segments <- st_split(line, blades) |> 
  st_collection_extract("LINESTRING")

We can see that segments comprises 6 linestrings, as expected:
segments
#> Geometry set for 6 features 
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -73.47588 ymin: 45.56858 xmax: -73.3353 ymax: 45.57874
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> First 5 geometries:
#> LINESTRING (-73.47588 45.57844, -73.47538 45.57...
#> LINESTRING (-73.44202 45.57115, -73.44156 45.57...
#> LINESTRING (-73.41764 45.5691, -73.41735 45.569...
#> LINESTRING (-73.40452 45.56983, -73.40366 45.56...
#> LINESTRING (-73.40304 45.56991, -73.40205 45.56...

And they fit perfectly along the original line
plot(line)
for(i in seq(length(segments))) plot(segments[i], col = i, add = TRUE, lwd = 3)


Created on 2024-10-30 with reprex v2.1.0

How weird... after your answers I had noticed that the st_nearest_points functions gave point-like segments, out of curiosity I went on with st_split, and it looks like your observation works. Thank you very much!

Just to comment on
st_snap(pts, line, tol=1e-9)

, st_snap snaps only to vertices. As segment lengths of the linestring built from your included coordinates range from ~13m to ~745m, your post-snap coordinates are most likely identical (as in identical() ) to sampled coordinates when using 1e-9 units for tolerance.
I'd also be cautious when using Web Mercator (EPSG:3857) for anything that's related to measurements and tolerances, e.g. when projected to 3857, length of your line is 16023.1m while in UTM it's 11231.32m and in WGS84 it's 11203.64m (measured through sf::st_length() with s2 enabled).
First transforming back to unprojected CRS and then splitting is also complicating things. If you need to continue to work with WGS84, transform after you've finished with operations that required projected coordinates.

One convenient method to segmentize line by sampled points would be through sfnetworks::st_network_blend():
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.12.1, GDAL 3.8.4, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(sfnetworks)
library(mapview)

# epsg:32618: UTM Z16
line <- 
  st_as_sfc("LINESTRING (-73.47588 45.57844, -73.47538 45.57834, -73.47487 45.57824, -73.47451 45.57817, -73.47374 45.57799, -73.47288 45.57779, -73.4724 45.57767, -73.47209 45.5776, -73.47176 45.57752, -73.4714 45.57744, -73.47099 45.57734, -73.47056 45.57725, -73.47022 45.57716, -73.46961 45.57703, -73.46928 45.57696, -73.46897 45.57689, -73.46873 45.57684, -73.46857 45.57681, -73.4684 45.57678, -73.46819 45.57674, -73.46788 45.57668, -73.46748 45.5766, -73.46716 45.57654, -73.46678 45.57647, -73.46651 45.57642, -73.46621 45.57636, -73.46587 45.5763, -73.46556 45.57623, -73.46527 45.57617, -73.46498 45.57611, -73.46424 45.57598, -73.46377 45.57588, -73.46233 45.57557, -73.46164 45.57541, -73.46122 45.57531, -73.45898 45.57478, -73.45831 45.57463, -73.45798 45.57456, -73.45766 45.57449, -73.45705 45.57436, -73.45498 45.57391, -73.4544 45.57379, -73.4507 45.573, -73.44766 45.57235, -73.44441 45.57166, -73.44156 45.57105, -73.43243 45.5691, -73.43218 45.56905, -73.43198 45.56901, -73.43175 45.56896, -73.43155 45.56892, -73.43134 45.56889, -73.43113 45.56885, -73.43095 45.56882, -73.43078 45.5688, -73.43053 45.56877, -73.43032 45.56874, -73.43013 45.56871, -73.42994 45.56869, -73.42973 45.56867, -73.42956 45.56866, -73.42937 45.56864, -73.4292 45.56863, -73.42901 45.56862, -73.42883 45.56861, -73.42861 45.5686, -73.42839 45.56859, -73.42815 45.56858, -73.42789 45.56858, -73.42764 45.56858, -73.42736 45.56858, -73.4271 45.56859, -73.42685 45.5686, -73.42659 45.56861, -73.42634 45.56862, -73.42605 45.56864, -73.42577 45.56865, -73.42225 45.56885, -73.42144 45.5689, -73.41945 45.569, -73.41828 45.56907, -73.41735 45.56912, -73.41703 45.56914, -73.41661 45.56916, -73.41598 45.5692, -73.41535 45.56923, -73.41287 45.56937, -73.41079 45.56948, -73.41015 45.56952, -73.40708 45.56969, -73.40558 45.56977, -73.4051 45.5698, -73.40366 45.56988, -73.40205 45.56996, -73.40055 45.57005, -73.39993 45.57008, -73.39943 45.57011, -73.39913 45.57013, -73.39886 45.57015, -73.39862 45.57017, -73.39828 45.5702, -73.39802 45.57022, -73.39779 45.57025, -73.39755 45.57027, -73.39734 45.5703, -73.39711 45.57032, -73.39681 45.57036, -73.39648 45.5704, -73.39609 45.57046, -73.38743 45.57163, -73.38551 45.57189, -73.38328 45.57219, -73.38275 45.57228, -73.3822 45.57236, -73.3809 45.57253, -73.37786 45.57295, -73.37743 45.57301, -73.3727 45.57364, -73.37035 45.57396, -73.36803 45.57428, -73.36627 45.57452, -73.36414 45.5748, -73.36278 45.57499, -73.36221 45.57505, -73.36151 45.57514, -73.361 45.57521, -73.35975 45.57538, -73.35831 45.57558, -73.35577 45.57592, -73.35447 45.57609, -73.35367 45.5762, -73.35283 45.57632, -73.35195 45.57644, -73.35133 45.57652, -73.35059 45.57662, -73.34979 45.57673, -73.34637 45.57719, -73.34551 45.5773, -73.34409 45.5775, -73.34146 45.57785, -73.33933 45.57814, -73.33868 45.57823, -73.33827 45.57829, -73.33789 45.57834, -73.33755 45.57839, -73.33727 45.57843, -73.33692 45.57848, -73.33661 45.57853, -73.33628 45.57858, -73.33584 45.57865, -73.3353 45.57874)"
            , crs = 4326) |> 
  st_transform(line_wgs84, crs = 32618)

set.seed(1)
pts <- 
  st_line_sample(line, n = 5) |> 
  st_cast("POINT")

# to geospatial network, blend points, extract network edges
seg <- 
  as_sfnetwork(line) |> 
  st_network_blend(pts) |> 
  st_as_sf("edges")
seg
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 618908.9 ymin: 5047317 xmax: 629875.9 ymax: 5048592
#> Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 18N
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>    from    to                                                                  x
#>   <int> <int>                                                   <LINESTRING [m]>
#> 1     1     3 (618908.9 5048341, 618948.1 5048330, 618988.1 5048320, 619016.4 5…
#> 2     3     4 (619989.6 5048037, 620026.3 5048025, 620059.3 5048015, 620235.2 5…
#> 3     4     5 (622148.5 5047417, 622319.1 5047368, 622338.7 5047363, 622354.4 5…
#> 4     5     6 (624375.1 5047481, 624412.7 5047484, 624450.1 5047488, 624562.3 5…
#> 5     6     7 (626582 5047884, 626602 5047888, 626969.6 5047966, 627152.2 50480…
#> 6     7     2 (628778.9 5048352, 629015.8 5048402, 629082.7 5048416, 629193 504…
mapview(seg, zcol = "from", lwd = 3, color = \(n) RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n, "Accent"), legend = FALSE)


Created on 2024-10-31 with reprex v2.1.1

A precious add-on, as I had not found this function. Any reason to prefer st_network_blend over st_split?

Depends on the task.  Without knowing any background, I'd say I'd use it here just for convenience. It's not so much for splitting than adding new nodes to the network, e.g for routing tasks.
